# Spring Kafka Consumer with database

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

How can I  execute the below in a transaction. My requirement is message offset should not be committed to Kafka if the  DB calls fails .Kafka consumer configuration is  here https://pastebin.com/kq5S9Jrx

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${general.topic.name}" , groupId = "${general.topic.group.id}" )
    public void consume(String message,@Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment ack) 
    {
        logger.debug(String.format("Message recieved -> %s", message));
        
        // start transaction
        dbservice.validateMessage(message);
        
        dbservice.saveInDB(message);
        ack.acknowledge();
        // end transaction
}
```

Comment: In general, the suggestion would be to use Kafka Connect to handle database writes, and not implement that in your own code.

Comment: In any case, `try { dbservice.saveInDB(message); ack } catch ()` seems self-explanatory

Comment: no we don't to use Kafka Connect. Yes I had planned to do same .Checking if some better  solution is there like chainedkafkatransactionmanager .

Comment: AFAIK, that class is explicitly used for Kafka transactions, not external database operations

Comment: Linked from deleted answer https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring-boot-kafka-transactions-milo-felipe

Comment: The chained transaction manager is deprecated. In any case, there is no need to use Kafka transactions here since he is not publishing anything to Kafka. Kafka transactions are only needed when publishing. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
dbservice.validateMessage(message);

dbservice.saveInDB(message);
```

to a new method annotated with `@Transactional`.

then

```java
try {
    dbMethod(message);
    ack.ack();
catch (Exception e) {
    ack.nack(); // with an optional delay before redelivery
}
```

Or, simply use container managed offsets (no ack/nack) and let the exception propagate to the container, where a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` can manage the retries.

Comment: Russel   i was not aware `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` .Will have a look at it.Plus can tell me if its better idea to commit offsets manually or let kafka happen handle it.As these messages are financial transaction and losing them will translate to loss of $$ ,I can't afford to lose these messages.

Comment: The container will reliably commit the offsets; with `AckMode.BATCH` (default) after all records from the poll have been processed; with `AckMode.RECORD` after each record is processed. Record loss is not an issue.

Comment: See here for information about error handlers, publishing dead-letter records, etc https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: just 1 last question . Can  Consumer API consume the message twice if i implement the consumer code as show in my question ?In short is it exactly once processing?

Comment: Yes, you can get redelivery under several circumstances; it is at least once only; Kafka "Exactly Once" semantics only apply to `read -> process -> write` scenarios that ONLY INVOLVE KAFKA. Exactly Once means the whole thing will only be performed once, the `read -> process` part is at least once (and is repeated if the `-> write` fails). If the `process` component involves any other technology (such as a DB), you need to handle the possibility of duplicates. Since you are not publishing to Kafka at all, there is no benefit to using Kafka transactions.

Comment: I am not using Kafka transaction as you can see from configuration. I just wanted to commit offsets only when my message is read successfully. I got your point though.Well how can i get redelivery. If suppose Consume API  read offset=100 and commit it .Consumer API would move to offset 101 .How can it re read offset 101 ?

Comment: `1.` If your listener takes too long to process the records returned by a poll, the broker will force a rebalance and the offset commit will fail. `2.` If the server crashes (e.g. power failure) between the DB commit and the offset commit. To avoid #1, make sure `max.poll.interval.ms` is more than long enough to process `max.poll.records`.  #2 is a small window but a non-zero probability. If you store the topic/partition/offset in your DB, you can use it to detect duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Add @Transactional on Kafka Listener level

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${general.topic.name}" , groupId = "${general.topic.group.id}" )
@Transactional
public void consume(String message,@Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment ack) {
....
}
```

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync